# How to plot/print out of frame in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

If there is a lot of data to display, Jupyter Notebook wraps it into frame box woth scroll bars. Is is possible to disable this feature? Sometimes it is harmful:

[image]

Also, is it possible to disable fixed width at all?

---

If just disable scrolling, the plot is truncated, which is also not acceptable

[image]

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: @glhr just draw everything in wide enough and tall enough page, using only outermost scrollbars of a browser

Answer (score 2):

Disable auto-scroll by running the following in a cell first:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.prototype._should_scroll = function(lines) {
    return false;
}
```

Or via the user interface:

```
Cell -> All Output / Current Outputs -> Toggle Scrolling
```

Comment: Of course, I didn't mean disable scrolling and clip the data, which happens in the case